# How can i save all client Text chat in PeerJS Server?

Tags: logging, server, chat, peerjs

I want log all client Text chats on server side.
I want use this log for history of chats for my client.
Please help me for do this..?
my peerjs server :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;

var server = PeerServer({
  port: 9000,
  host: 'datis.site',
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('\datis/datis.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('\datis/datis.crt')
  }
server.on('connection', function(id) { console.log('connect_client_ID_'+id); });
server.on('disconnect', function(id) { console.log('disconnect_client_ID_'+id); });
});`
```

this "server.on" when client connected or disconnected to server acted but i look for some  function or sample code that when client send text message to another client listening this message and stored in db or log file.

Comment: Store it in a database

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's a place that people come to solve problems they are having. Part of the etiquette is that people are expected to use google and stack overflow to see if anyone has encountered the same problem. They then describe (with code snippets) what they have tried, and where they are having trouble. Your request shows no evidence of this.

Comment: How can log history of chats in PeerJS ??? I want stored chat history in the server side in peerjs ?  "there is no useful result in google search and stackoverflow " if you have experience about peerjs and peerjs-server; please, solved this question and help me truly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of the peerjs is to broker peer-to-peer connections between browsers. It does not carry any of the data or video/voice streams. So you can't log the chats from the server.

You will have to send the chat messages to your regular server for storing in a database.